# pic bitbang SPI library with variable frame length

Tags: pic, spi, bit-bang

Im trying to send an SPI frame that is 12 bits long using a pic 16F1455.

Im afraid i cant do this using the hardware SPI module , which has a fixed length of 8 bits.

I think i can do this with software SPI or bit-bang SPI.

Are there libraries that for this with variable length ?? (hopefully for cx8)

Comment: Even if there weren't libraries, it's not a huge effort to implement a bit-bang SPI: it's not worth the time "learning" one particular library.

Comment: i know its not that hard ... but why re-invent the wheel ??  
i just wanted to know of some well known library if there was one..thats all

Comment: unless you're looking for high-level features, such as buffering, it's not reinveintg the wheel: Is using the wheel (C or ASM instructions). In C you will make it in less than 10 lines, using a for loop. This will save you both the time of looking for the library, and the time to learn how to use it. 
Beside, this would be very useful from a learning viewpoint.

Comment: actually yes, I am looking for high level features such us "variable lenght" stop bit , and buffering would be nice too... So do you have any ideas of a good library like this ??? i mean , if you know so much about it... :)

Comment: I'm used to reinvent the wheel :) 

Beside, stop bit in an SPI? Perhaps are you referring to an USART instead? SPI and USART are two different things, even if some chips (e.g.) ATMEGAs can use the USART in SPI mode.

Comment: actually i'm using this to drive an USART....that's the deal....
i need tips for a good library men , not academic mambo jambo...

Comment: Yes, you can easily do that with for loop. I am not aware of any libraries that offer non multiple of 8 bits.